# Javascript key not populated in Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a object with keys/values but when I see the object, the keys are not populated correctly..

I expect the keys to be - 0,1,2,3 but it shows "index" as the key.

```
> categories = ["09/07/2016 00:00","09/07/2016 00:01","09/07/2016 00:02","09/07/2016 00:03","09/07/2016 00:04"]   
["09/07/2016 00:00", "09/07/2016 00:01", "09/07/2016 00:02", "09/07/2016 00:03", "09/07/2016 00:04"]

> rate_1 = [0.41,0.54,0.6,0.7,0.8]
[0.41, 0.54, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]

> dict = []
[]

> categories.forEach(function(ix,index){console.log(index)
    dict.push({index:rate_1[index]})
})
0
1
2
3
4

> JSON.stringify(dict)
"[{"index":0.41},{"index":0.54},{"index":0.6},{"index":0.7},{"index":0.8}]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this by wrapping `index` in square brackets (ES6 syntax):

```
dict.push({ [index]: rate_1[index]})
```

Without this, `index` is indeed taken as a literal, not as the variable.

```js
var categories = ["09/07/2016 00:00","09/07/2016 00:01","09/07/2016 00:02","09/07/2016 00:03","09/07/2016 00:04"];
var rate_1 = [0.41,0.54,0.6,0.7,0.8];
var dict = [];
categories.forEach(function(ix,index){
  dict.push({[index]:rate_1[index]})
});
result = JSON.stringify(dict);
console.log(result);
```

As a side note: this code lends itself for using `map` instead of `forEach`, saving you the explicit array initialisation and `push`. I just provide this for info; it is not related to your question ;-)

```js
var categories = ["09/07/2016 00:00","09/07/2016 00:01","09/07/2016 00:02","09/07/2016 00:03","09/07/2016 00:04"];
var rate_1 = [0.41,0.54,0.6,0.7,0.8];
var dict = categories.map(function(ix,index){
  return {[index]:rate_1[index]};
});
result = JSON.stringify(dict);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the map function, its much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Keys are interpreted as they are typed - they don't do a variable check. If you need a dynamic key - create the object first, then add the key/val:

```
var obj = {};
obj[index] = rate_1[index];
dict.push(obj)
```

Unless you can use ES6 syntax - then go with @trincot's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The existing solutions are correct, but this is a slightly cleaner and more functional alternative using `Array.prototype.map`, using vanilla Javascript.

```
var dict = rate_1.map(function(rate, idx) {
    var entry = {};
    entry[idx] = rate;
    return entry;
});
// dict is [{0: 0.41}, {1: 0.54}, ...]
```